# Autohotkey Input without requiring an endkey

Tags: input, autohotkey

I created this script to scan tapes (barcodes).
Once scanned it will create a space before, after and a dash at the end.

Example: "T51320L5" becomes " T51320L5 -"

Whenever this type of barcode is scanned it runs, but only once space is pressed.
I would like to make it so that no keypresses are required.
Only scanning the barcode.

The end "L5" is allways the same, so maybe there is something to be done with those keys as an endkey.
Only I don't know how to do it.

Example of barcodes I scan:

T71233L5 - T71243L5 - T71256L5 - T71263L5 - T71275L5 - T51308L5 - T51315L5 - T71209L5 - T71210L5 - T71219L5 - T71220L5 - AS0119L5

code is as below:

```
loop {
  Input, retrieved, V, {space}
  RegExMatch(retrieved, "\b\w\w\w\w\w\w[A-Z]\d\s", match)
  RegExMatch(match, "\b\w\w\w\w\w\w[A-Z]\d\s", output) 
  If (output != "")
    Sendinput, {bs 9}{space}%output%{space}-
}
```

Does anyone have advice on how to get it working without needing to press any keys.
Just scanning the barcode.

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on what type of barcode scanner you are using and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 solutions using the Input command options

1. Using the matchlist option

> MatchList
>
> A comma-separated list of key phrases, any of which will cause the Input to be terminated

The command would be the following:

```
Input, retrieved,* V,,L5
```

Each time the text "L5" is entered the input will stop.
You have to make sure "L5" never appears anywhere else in the barcode but the very end.

2. Using the length limit

> L: Length limit (e.g. L5). The maximum allowed length of the input. When the text reaches this length, the Input will be terminated

```
Input, retrieved,L8 V
```

When 8 characters are entered the input stops.
Make sure you have no other keyboard input at the time.